# Lodash set integer paths strange behavior

Tags: javascript, lodash

`_.set()` behaves strangely when setting a path which contains an integer. Here is an example:

```js
const object = {}

_.set(object, "wavelength.415", "foo");

console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
```

Upon running this code, the object will look something like this:

```
{"wavelength":[null,null,null,null,null,etc....,"foo"]}
```

Is there a way around this behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior (see this [issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1316)), use [`_.setWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#setWith) instead:

```js
const object = {}

_.setWith(object, "wavelength.415", "foo", Object);

console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```